# Flutter: Horizontal ListView view with different height contraint

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a horizontal list bar with fixed height 100 (used inside Column).
Height 100 is good for iPhone8.
But the pixel overflows in iPhone-X due to limited 100 height.
If I make it 140, both are good.  But the bar looks no good in iphone8.
So I want 120 height in one device and 140 in other device.
I thought I could achieve it using ConstrainedBox like below:

```
ConstrainedBox(constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 140), child: ListView(...))
```

But listview goes with 140 height all the time.
So How to achive dynamic height contraint for different device?

Sample widget:

```
class MyHorizontalBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 100, // 140
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          _myCard(),
          _myCard(),
          _myCard(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _myCard(){
    return Container(
      width: 115,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('Top', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
          Text('Middle', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
          Text('Bottom', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using MediaQuery.of(context).size.height or width in place of constant height and width.

Comment: Applied this idea, it did play nice on vertical mode, but get flipped once the device rotates horizontal. Though it's possible to fix that as well, felt like a hack.

Comment: But this idea took me in the direction of "MediaQuery.of(ctx).textScaleFactor". And scaling the widget height along with textScaleFactor gave me better visual in my case. So, going with that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) widget. But such problems are usually solved with a [flexible layout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).

e.g. defining your horizontal bar height as 1/3 of available height.

Comment: It's used inside Column, so any flex like expanded goes unbounded. But LayoutBuilder suggestion is helpful to debug the issue. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaQuery.of(context)

try the following code.

```
class MyHorizontalBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double magicNumber = 5; // Try playing with this number to get the appearence. 
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / magicNumber, 
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          _myCard(),
          _myCard(),
          _myCard(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _myCard() {
    return Container(
      width: 115,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
              Text('Top', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
              Text('Middle', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
              Text('Bottom', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Try playing with the variable magicNumber.